# Bool does not conform to protocol

Tags: swift

I just started coding not too long ago so I'm not too experienced. Anyway, I feel like this is a simple problem yet I cannot seem to fix it.

I am getting a "Type 'Bool' does not conform to protocol 'IntegerLiteralConvertible'

I believe that the problem lies within this line:

```
var photoSelected: Bool = false
```

because I get the error on this line:

```
self.photoSelected = 0
```

I know to most this may seem super easy, but I've looked around and I'm not too sure how to fix this particular problem.

I appreciate all the help, Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

0 does not convert to type `Bool` in swift. Set `self.photoSelected = false` and the error message will disappear. If you're dealing with a numeric input you can use an equality operator.

```
self.photoSelected = (x == 0)
```

Comment: Ah, awesome that fixed it. I knew it was something simple but my limited swift knowledge made it hard to figure out haha... I appreciate the quick response, thank you!